# reading data through bluetooth using flutter_bluetooth_serial package

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

currently I'm working in a small app connected with a device through bluetooth with flutter and flutter_bluetooth_serial package.

so sending data works fine for me using this function:

```
void _sendMessage() async {
connection.output.add(utf8.encode("data here" + "\r\n"));
await connection.output.allSent;
}
```

but I don't know how to read data and print it for example in console
please can you provide a function can solve the issue?
thanks

Answer (score -1):

Did you give the simple example they provided a try? It has a *.listen* callback to receive data from connected devices. Here's the example code, do give it a try:

```
try {
    BluetoothConnection connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address);
    print('Connected to the device');

    connection.input.listen((Uint8List data) {
        print('Data incoming: ${ascii.decode(data)}');
        
    }).onDone(() {
        print('Disconnected by remote request');
    });
}
catch (exception) {
    print('Cannot connect, exception occured');
}
```

Comment: no this not working for me because I didn't understand it maybe,